Determine if popstate event handler was trigger programmatically?
I'm calling history.back() and history.forward(), but I want to have a popstate handler just for events triggered by the browser. In other words, I'd like to ignore popstates triggered programmatically. Is this possible?
The only possible solutions I can think of involve keeping track of all the history states in my webapp, then every time I call history.back(), I'd know what state would be in event.state, so I know what to ignore. However, I can think of edge cases where this might not work: if a lot of navigations happen before popstate runs, which is unlikely but possible.
Is there a better way?
Context:
Currently, my webapp updates app state on popstate, but this is noticeably laggy on slower devices. E.g. user clicks an in-app "back" button -> trigger history.back() -> popstate handler -> update app state -> rerender. Instead, I want to change it to: user clicks an in-app "back" button -> update app state -> rerender -> trigger history.back(). I still need the popstate handler for browser backs. If the user navigates multiple times very quickly, then the popstate handler would behave weirdly, which I want to want to avoid.

If you just want to avoid the ones you did cause, you can store a semaphore that you'd switch off after the next popstate event after your call. So something like ignore_popstate = true; addEventListener("popstate", () => ignore_popstate = false, { once: true }); history.back();.

Yeah that'll work 99.9% of the time, but it's possible that a history.back() and a browser back both occur before popstate runs

I don't think it is, no. The popstate is fired in the next task, before the browser's one could be handled. What could happen though is that a synchronous update is triggered after this line (e.g. hashchange through location)
